# Spring Web MVC: Perform FORWARD with DeferredResult

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, forward, deferred-result

We use `DeferredResult` in Controller methods. How is it possible to perform a **FORWARD** to another controller method?

I am aware of how to perform a REDIRECT, but I do not want the round trip to the browser and back.
I am also aware of how to perform a FORWARD by returning a `ModelAndView` or by returning a `String` from the controller method.
But I am restricted to use `DeferredResult`.

How is it possible to **perform a FORWARD with `DeferredResult`** similar to returning a string like ´ `"forward:/forwardUrl"`?